# Output Users ISP on Webpage

Tags: php, show, hostname

I am trying to display users ISP.

I managed to get their IP and their hostname but I'm having trouble displaying only their ISP.

The PHP code I used for hostname is:

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $hostname;
?>
```

This works but it displays 201-217-12-214.static.tpgi.com.au and not just the Hostname.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to look up their address in a `WHOIS` database. Or you could subscribe to a geolocation service that provides this information.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "display only their ISP"? What do you want to be displayed for that address? You want to get "TPG Internet Pty Ltd" from that?

Comment: p2location, MaxMind, Tamo Soft and IPligence ...

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to get Barmar :)